# Override Ipad / Iphone no resize function for webpages

Tags: iphone, ipad, resize, responsive-design

I have made a webpage using the 960 grid system. And I have made it nice and responsive, following the excellent advice found in www.alistapart.com

So when developing the CSS for my new webpage I kept checking in [Dreamweaver's Multiscreen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgEEpYAHjEM) viewport testing option and found that my pages were stacking up nicely on smaller screens. No miniature text, no need for pinch and zoom.

Then when testing page live, I learn that Ipad and Iphone [does not resize windows](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.htm) and I can only get a miniaturized version of my full screen webpage.

I am hoping there is a simple CSS way to override this, so that my webpage stacks in a responsive manner also on apple devices.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for... but if you place this line in the <head> tags of your web page/s: <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=false" />  Naturally, change 320 to the width of the device.

Comment: looks like what I need. could you dumb it down for me and help me put this in the CSS? saves me adding it to header in all sub pages.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible - unless you had some Javascript that detected the device, the screen size and orientation etc and then switched between the relevant values on the fly, as a user was on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try a fluid grid option, such as [sprysoft](http://www.spry-soft.com/) [variable grid system](http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/) which is based on 960.gs, though it will still have a definite grid layout (just % based instead of px based)

Comment: Yes it is currently in a spysoft variable fluid grid. But with iPhone not resizing the safari window it really makes no difference. You will only see a miniaturized version of the page at full 1024 width, and be forced to use pinch and zoom.